# TypeScript - React Context consumer doesn't re-render the main component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I've implemented a react context structure for my application, it works correctly and changes the states I've defined. But the main problem is that the UI component (in which I have my consumer) does not re-renders.
Here's my code in TypeScript:

```
class Home extends Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <DataProvider>
        <MainComponent />
      </DataProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

My Context:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export const dataContext = React.createContext({
  state: {
    temp: 0,
  },
  setGeneralState: () => {
  /* */
  },
});

export default class DataProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    temp: 1,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <dataContext.Provider
        value={{
          state: this.state,
          setGeneralState: () =>
            this.setState({
              temp: 999,
            }),
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </dataContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

And the consumer in UI:

```
<dataContext.Consumer>
   {(context) => (
        <React.Fragment>
        <p>Temp Value: {context.state.temp}</p>
          <button onClick={context.setGeneralState}>
          Press Me
          </button>
        </React.Fragment>
        )}
 </dataContext.Consumer>
```

So when I press the button, it should set the `temp` state to 999 and show it in UI, but it only changes the UI when some actions take place which the render function in the UI operates. I should note that the state is changed in React DevTools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solve the problem! It was due to a mismatch between `react` and `react-dom` packages, where react was *16.8.6* and react-dom was *16.5.0*. After upgrading react-dom, it now works like a charm :)